# Know when the device registers to the roaming network?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, roaming

I need to know when the device registers to the roaming network. Is there any intent broadcasted or any other way how I can know this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a broadcast receiver for **ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**....in the onreceive check for the current network info to check for roaming...